# Why is the 'active' class not being assigned to the content list items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

Below is a plugin I wrote for tabs. I'm sure there's a better approach to writing this, but that will come later when I start to refine this plugin. It's a learning-in-progress personal project. The problem is that when I click one of the tabs, the 'active' class is not being assigned to the corresponding content li tag. I'm assigning the id's to each of the li's using for loops.

If I remove `(cEvent + 1)` from the loop that assigns the 'active' class to the correct li tag, then it will assign an 'active' class to all li tags - because of this I know the selector is correct. It's when I add `(cEvent + 1)` in the loop that it doesn't assign anything.

The section in question is: `// Click Event: Open New Tab`

Thank you all very much for your help.

```
(function(){
$.fn.sctabs = function(options){
    var defaults = {
        tabsTheme       : 'default',
        tabsOrientation : 'horizontal', // horizontal, vertical
        tabsClassName   : 'tab',
        contentClassName: 'tabcontent',
        activeClass     : 'active',
        initActiveItem  : ':first-child',
        tabsEffOpen     : 'slideDown',
        tabsEffClose    : 'slideUp'
    };

    var options = $.extend(defaults,options);

    console.log('Tabs Plugin Successfully Loaded');

    // Add Theme
    $(this).addClass(options.tabsTheme);

    // Set Tabs Orientation
    $(this).addClass(options.tabsOrientation);

    // Add Initial Classes
    $('ul.popuptabslist li').addClass(options.tabsClassName);
    $('ul.popuptabsoutput li').addClass(options.contentClassName);

    // Assign Tabs/Content to Var
    var tabsList = $('ul.popuptabslist li');
    var contentsList = $('ul.popuptabsoutput li');

    // Set the stopping point dynamically
    tabsLength = tabsList.length;
    contentsLength = contentsList.length;

    // Tabs Loop: Start the index at 0
    t = 0;
    for (; t < tabsLength; t++) {
        tabsList[t].id = "tab" + (t + 1);

        console.log('Tab id' + (t + 1) + ' Created');
    }

    // Contents Loop: Start the index at 0
    c = 0;
    for (; c < contentsLength; c++) {
        contentsList[c].id = "content" + (c + 1);

        console.log('Tab Content id' + (c + 1) + ' Created');
    }

    // Set Initial Item Open
    $('ul.popuptabslist ' + options.initActiveItem + ', ul.popuptabsoutput ' + options.initActiveItem)
        .addClass(options.activeClass);

    // Click Event: Open New Tab
    cEvent = 0;
    for (; cEvent < tabsLength; cEvent++){
        $('ul.popuptabslist li#tab' + (cEvent + 1)).on('click', function(){

            // Remove Active Class on Click
            $('ul.popuptabslist li.tab').removeClass(options.activeClass);
            $(this).parent().parent().find('ul.popuptabsoutput li.tabcontent').removeClass(options.activeClass);

            // Add Active Class to Clicked Tab and Corresponding Content
            $(this).addClass(options.activeClass);
            $('ul.popuptabsoutput li#content' + (cEvent + 1)).addClass(options.activeClass);
            $(this).parent().parent().find('ul.popuptabsoutput li#content' + (cEvent + 1)).addClass(options.activeClass);

            console.log($(this).attr('id').toUpperCase() + ' clicked');
        });
    }

};
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle I put together for it: http://jsfiddle.net/B8e8W/

Comment: You can just edit your question and add the fiddle in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the infamous world of closure that you are dealing with. While you are binding event on the tag, the variable `cEvent` is getting incremented, which mean that each event will have the last instance of `cEvent` as `id`.

You can use a self closing function :

```
(function(cEvent){
            $('ul.popuptabslist li#tab' + (cEvent + 1)).on('click', function(){

                // Remove Active Class on Click
                $('ul.popuptabslist li.tab').removeClass(options.activeClass);
                $(this).parent().parent().find('ul.popuptabsoutput li.tabcontent').removeClass(options.activeClass);

                // Add Active Class to Clicked Tab and Corresponding Content
                $(this).addClass(options.activeClass);
                $('ul.popuptabsoutput li#content' + (cEvent + 1)).addClass(options.activeClass);
                $(this).parent().parent().find('ul.popuptabsoutput li#content' + (cEvent + 1)).addClass(options.activeClass);

                console.log($(this).attr('id').toUpperCase() + ' clicked');
            });
        })(cEvent);
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/B8e8W/1/